# cannot read propert 'db' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

mangodb connection:

```
let express = require('express');
let mongodb = require('mongodb');

let app = express();
let db;

let connectionString = "mongodb+srv://todoAppUser:<password>@cluster0.qooyl.mongodb.net/todoApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongodb.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, client){
    db = client.db();
  // console.log(db);
    app.listen(3000);
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

HTML Template:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="jumbotron p-3 shadow-sm">
  <form method="post" action="/create-item">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <input name="item" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="form-control mr-3" type="text" style="flex: 1;">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Item</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
    </html>`);
});
```

After Submitting form Post method:

```
app.post('/create-item', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('items').insertOne({text: req.body.item}, function() {
        res.send("Form Submitted");
    });
});
```

I am using nodemon as server, while saving file facing error, cannot read property of 'db' undefined

Please help to solve this issue..

Comment: You forgot `if(err){ throw err; }` at the start of the function where `err` is received.

Comment: @SebastianSimon i already got error in console like cannot read proeprty of 'db' undefined..

Please see image in: https://ibb.co/4PtqM3t

Comment: That error is saying client is undefined, which is a regular javascript error. You need to be logging the error mongodb gives you which will you tell you why client is undefined. So add the code Sebastian suggested.